# ASP.NET MVC Core 2 & Angular 5 Beginner - component not showing up without app-root

Tags: typescript, angular5, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to get a super basic ASP.NET Core 2 & Angular 5 web application running and am having an issue with a component not showing up, unless I also include the app-root component.

So the symptoms that I'm getting are that if I include the **app-root** in either Home or Gallery Index.cshtml then it shows up just fine, if I include the **thumbnail** below that, then that also shows up just fine. However if I remove the **app-root** and keep the **thumbnail**, then nothing shows up.

I'm sure I'm missing something super basic and I assume it is because of dependencies or the app.module, but I do not understand Angular well enough at this point to figure it out. I've spent hours googling and trying to figure it out myself to no success :(

All I would like to do is to have a bunch of components that I am able to independently use through different views either together or separately.

Here's the github repo link to the project: https://github.com/rpasechnikov/AspNetCore2Angular5EfCoreSampleWebsite

Thanks!!

Comment: Please, can you add the code from both components and the html main file with the ways you are starting with AppComponent or GalleryThumbnail?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I've updated the OP above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some experimentation, I found the problem.

When you place components in the main module's `bootstrap` array, Angular expects **all** of them to be rendered on the page. The components in the `bootstrap` array are not optional, but mandatory. In fact, except when you add both components to the HTML files, you're getting an exception (check your console). The difference is that, when you just miss `GalleryThumbnail`, the error happens after Angular has rendered `AppComponent`, which allows you to believe nothing was wrong, when in fact it was. Yes, the page seems to be functional, though I wouldn't trust that it will work correctly.

The problem when you do not include `AppComponent` is that, in your module, that component is the fist one added to the bootstrap array, so Angular tries to find `<app-root>` on the page. When it doesn't, it launchs an exception and the bootstrapping ends abruptly, so it never gets to render `GalleryThumbnail`.

In conclusion, you can't use the bootstrap array to choose between root components. If you want to initialise only one of them, you must:

1. Change `AppComponent`'s name to something else (`HomeComponent`?)
2. Create a new `AppComponent` and, in its template, you just render either `HomeComponent` or `GalleryThumbnail`, based on whichever criteria you want (page URL, some global variable you add to the `.cshtml` page ...)

You can also use routing to determine which component to show, adding a RouteOutlet to this new `AppComponent`'s template instead of using `ngIf` or `ngSwitch` to select which component to render. This way you only have one `.cshtml` file, and, based on the URL, Angular will render one component or another. This should be your approach when dealing with various pages in Angular, as it is a framework designed for creating SPAs. It is a bit more complicated than just using `ngIf` in this simple case, but it also is a much more scalable solution, so it's definitely the way to go if you plan on your app to grow and have more routes in the future.

If you decide to change your approach to this one, make sure that you add routes in your ASP.NET core app that match those defined in Angular, and that all of them return your Home/Index.cshtml page.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! That makes sense!

I think part of my confusion is lack of clear understanding of angular Components vs Modules and how do those get consumed inside of my .cshtml Views.

What I thought is that I would create my views inside of .cshtml files with a few components in them. What your answer seems to suggest to me is that I should be creating a root component and designing the whole view in that component? I think I am struggling figuring out where the boundary between .cshtml files and angular component lies.

Comment: Yes, that should be the way with Angular. The HTML page in Angular should be a mere support to host the Angular application. You can put in the page static content, though, like a header or a footer, or other content related to SEO (as lots of search engines can't process Angular applications)